# Match whole word (Visual Studio style)

Tags: regex

I am trying to add Match Whole Word search to my small application.
I want it to do the same thing that Visual Studio is doing.
So for example, below code should work fine:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            String input = "[  abc() *abc  ]";

            Match(input, "abc", 2);
            Match(input, "abc()", 1);
            Match(input, "*abc", 1);
            Match(input, "*abc ", 1);            
        }

        private void Match(String input, String pattern, int expected)
        {
            String escapedPattern = Regex.Escape(pattern);
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b" + escapedPattern + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (mc.Count != expected)
            {
                throw new Exception("match whole word isn't working");
            }
        }
    }
```

Searching for "abc" works fine but other patterns return 0 results.
I think \b is inadequate but i am not sure what to use.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\b` metacharacter matches on a word-boundary between an alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric character. The strings that end with non-alphanumeric characters end up failing to match since `\b` is working as expected.

To perform a proper whole word match that supports both types of data you need to:

- use `\b` before or after any alphanumeric character
- use `\B` (capital `B`) before or after any non-alphanumeric character
- not use `\B` if the first or last character of the pattern is intentionally a non-alphanumeric character, such as your final example with a trailing space

Based on these points you need to have additional logic to check the incoming search term to shape it into the appropriate pattern. `\B` works in the opposite manner of `\b`. If you don't use `\B` then you could incorrectly end up with partial matches. For example, the word `foo*abc` would incorrectly be matched with a pattern of `@"\*abc\b"`.

To demonstrate:

```
string input = "[  abc() *abc foo*abc ]";
string[] patterns =
{
    @"\babc\b",     // 3
    @"\babc\(\)\B", // 1
    @"\B\*abc\b",   // 1, \B prefix ensures whole word match, "foo*abc" not matched
    @"\*abc\b",     // 2, no \B prefix so it matches "foo*abc"
    @"\B\*abc "     // 1
};

foreach (var pattern in patterns)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pattern: " + pattern);
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
    Console.WriteLine("Matches found: " + matches.Count);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + match.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@"(?<!\w)" + escapedPattern + @"(?!\w)"
```

`\b` is defined in terms of the presence or absence of "word" characters both before and after the current position.  You only care about the what's *before* the first character and what's *after* the last one.

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` is a zero-width assertion that matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Letters, digits and underscores are word characters. `*`, SPACE, and parens are non-word characters.  therefore, when you use `\b*abc\b` as your pattern, it does not match your input, because * is non-word.  Likewise for your pattern involving parens.

To solve this, 
You will need to eliminate the `\b` in cases where your input (unescaped) pattern begins or ends with non-word characters.

---

```
    public void Run()
    {
        String input = "[  abc() *abc  ]";

        Match(input, @"\babc\b", 2);
        Match(input, @"\babc\(\)", 1);
        Match(input, @"\*abc\b", 1);
        Match(input, @"\*abc\b ", 1);
    }

    private void Match(String input, String pattern, int expected)
    {
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine((mc.Count == expected)? "PASS ({0}=={1})" : "FAIL ({0}!={1})",
                          mc.Count, expected);
    }
```